# UISearch bar not calling searchBarTextDidBeginEditing

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have a simple view controller with a **uisearchbar** and a **uitable**. 
My problem is that when search bar is tapped I see delegate function **searchBarShouldBeginEditing** being called but not **searchBarTextDidBeginEditing**(and because of that keyboard is not opened and search is not editable)

I tried to implement delegate function **searchBarShouldBeginEditing**  returning YES, set searchbar as first responder, but no way I get **searchBarTextDidBeginEditing** called...

Any idea what could be happening??

Some code:

controller.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UISearchBarDelegate>
{
   UISearchBar * searchbar;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar* searchbar;

@end
```

controller.m

```
@synthesize searchbar;

- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)sel {
    NSLog(@"Queried about %@", NSStringFromSelector(sel));
    return [super respondsToSelector:sel];
}

- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"searchBarShouldBeginEditing -Are we getting here??"); 
    return YES;  
}  
-(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    NSLog(@"searchBarTextDidBeginEditing -Are we getting here??");  
}
```

Of cousrse my class have plenty more code (that surely is affecting somehow searchbar) but if someone has got similar problems with searchbar it would be very apreciated its response ;)

I tryed to make simple application with only searchbar and obviously it works...

**EDITING:**

Testing a little bit I discovered that it is not something related with uisearchbar as I added a TextField getting same result (just textFieldShouldStartEditing delegate function being called)

Application has all view controllers inside a UITabBar cotroller, but I do not think this can cause all this mess...

**EDITING2:**

Really strange behaviour: Setting IBAction function to TouchDown event of a UITextfield works perfectly but setting IBAction function to EditingDidBegin never gets fired...

Why this event could not be called??

Comment: Can you post your codes?

Comment: I am having the opposite behaviour on my searchBar. I get searchBarTextDidBeginEditing but not searchBarShouldBeginEditing... Maybe Apple messed up something in the latest SDK? What SDK are you using?

Comment: I m sorry, but I have not anymore the code... I think that I solved it recreating the whole project (and still do not know what was failling in that first one.)

Answer (score 13):

did you set the delegate property?

```
searchbar.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I did both ways through interface builder, and throught code (and both  at same time XD ) Anyway I dont think this is the problem as one of delegate function do get called (searchBarShouldBeginEditing). Thanks for the answer by the way!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you somewhere call `[searchbar resignFirstResponder]`. It was the case in my similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was converting from a standalone UISearchBar to a searchBar integrated into the UINavigationBar.

In converting my code, I was still allocating the UISearchBar and setting the delegate for that.  What I should have been doing was configuring the searchBar that comes as part of of the UISearchController, and setting the delegate of that,

```
self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
```

Once I did that, my delegate methods started firing!